# JavaScript Array of Strings with indexOf Or an Object with strings as fieldnames

Tags: javascript

I'm have an array of strings:

```
const arr = ["foo", "bar"];
```

---

Is it better to check content with `indexOf`:

```
if (arr.indexOf("foo") > 0)
```

Or should I convert it to an object with the strings as fieldnames:

```
const arrObj = _.keyBy(arr);
/* resulting arrObj = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar: "bar"
}; */
if(arrObj.foo)
```

I'm getting the array only once, so I'm only converting to object once, but I'm checking for the strings repeatedly.

I'm thinking the `indexOf` is `O(n)` and field access is `O(1)`.

Comment: you could take a `Set`.

Comment: I didn't realize javascript had a `Set`. An object is basically a `HashMap` and a `HashMap` of booleans is just a `Set` anyways right.

Comment: Unless you have a huge number of items in your array, it is unlikely that there will be a noticeable performance difference.